# UIBarButtonItemのactionを引数無しにする方法

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

普通StoryboardからDragAndDropすると引数(sender: Any)ができてしまう。
これを消して引数なしのfuncにしたい。

Answer (score 1):

先に引数なしのfuncをコーディングすれば可能

1. コードを書く

```swift
@IBAction func onXxxBarButtonDidTouch() {
  print("XxxBarButtonDidTouch!!")
}
```

2. コードからStoryboardのUIBarButtonへと、outletの線を引く